# Java Timer Animation

Tags: java, javafx

Необходимо по таймеру увеличивать и уменьшать сферу например за 5 секунд увеличить и за 5 секунд уменьшить, этот код работает, ну я не знаю как указать время.

```
private void prepareAnimation() {

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        double i = 0;
        double step = 2.4;
        int s = 0;
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            i += step;
            s++;
            sphere.translateZProperty().set(i);
            if (s == 1000) {
                step *= -1;
                s = 0;
            }
        }
    };
   timer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант с использованием ScaleTransition:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(100.0);
    HBox root = new HBox(sphere);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Scale Transition");
    stage.show();


    // Set up a scale transition for the sphere
    ScaleTransition st = new ScaleTransition(Duration.seconds(5), sphere);
    st.setFromX(1.0);
    st.setToX(0.2);
    st.setFromY(1.0);
    st.setToY(0.2);
    st.setCycleCount(ScaleTransition.INDEFINITE);
    st.setAutoReverse(true);
    st.play();
}
```

Время задается в конструкторе ScaleTransition.